# How Clojure uses reducer to implement map?

Tags: clojure

I am reading Seven Concurrency Models in Seven Weeks and have no prior knowledge about Clojure. I have a really hard time understanding the code below, which implements map function over collections (reducible).

I've put my specific questions in the code body, but I am more interested in the code logic. I understand coll-reduce is defined for a bunch of sequence objects, but how it is used in this code to implement map is really confusing to me.

Any hint is appreciated.

```
;---
; Excerpted from "Seven Concurrency Models in Seven Weeks",
; published by The Pragmatic Bookshelf.
; Copyrights apply to this code. It may not be used to create training material, 
; courses, books, articles, and the like. Contact us if you are in doubt.
; We make no guarantees that this code is fit for any purpose. 
; Visit http://www.pragmaticprogrammer.com/titles/pb7con for more book information.
;---
(ns reducers.core
  (:require [clojure.core.protocols :refer [CollReduce coll-reduce]]
            [clojure.core.reducers :refer [CollFold coll-fold]]))

(defn make-reducer [reducible transformf]
  (reify
    CollReduce
    (coll-reduce [_ f1]
      (coll-reduce reducible (transformf f1) (f1)))   ; what's the meaning of (f1) here?
    (coll-reduce [_ f1 init]
      (coll-reduce reducible (transformf f1) init))))

(defn my-map [mapf reducible]
  (make-reducer reducible
    (fn [reducef]
      (fn [acc v]
        (reducef acc (mapf v))))))

(into [] (my-map (partial * 2) [1 2 3 4]))  ; I don't really understand what's reducef and what's acc here
```

Answer (score 0):

First, map, mapcat, filter, etc. can all be implemented in terms of reduce. Consider the following naive implementation of map for vectors (with more verbose names to add clarity):

```
(defn my-map [mapping-function collection]
  (reduce
    (fn [accumulator element]
      (conj accumulator (mapping-function element)))
    []
    collection))

(println (my-map (partial + 2) [1 2 3])) ; prints [3 4 5]
```

Rough equivalent for Javascript arrays if you come from curly-brace land

```js
function myMap(mappingFunction, collection) {
  return collection.reduce(function(acc, element) {
    acc.push(mappingFunction(element));
    return acc;
  }, []);
}
```

The reason for all the extra verbiage in the version you posted is, as far as I can tell, that it's polymorphic over various collection types and runs reasonably fast whereas my dinky little version only works for vectors and is slow. As for your specific questions about the code:

```
(coll-reduce reducible (transformf f1) (f1)))   ; what's the meaning of (f1) here?
```

Here `f1` is a generic reducing function.

> I don't really understand what's reducef and what's acc here

Think about what a map-defined-in-terms-of-reduce does:

1. Take an item from a collection
2. Perform a function on it
3. Add the altered value to a new collection (usually of the same type).

Here, `mapf` is the function we use to transform elements of the collection, `acc` is the accumulator: the new collection being built up, and `reducef` is the reducing function responsible for taking the output of the transformation along with the accumulated new collection and joining them.